# Сортировка слиянием без рекурсии

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, сортировка, сортировка-слиянием

Функция сортирует массив экземпляров структуры `contact` по полю `sname`,для довольно больших массивов возникает проблема с переполнением стека из-за рекурсии в 5-6 строках. Как можно реализовать эту сортировку без использования рекурсии?

```
void MergeSort(contact* buf, int first, int last)
{
if (first >= last - 1) return;
int mid = (first + last) / 2;
MergeSort(buf, first, mid);
MergeSort(buf, mid, last);

contact * mas = new contact[last - first];
for (int i = first; i < last; ++i)
    mas[i - first] = buf[i];
int l = 0, r = mid - first;
for (int i = first; i < last; ++i)
{
    if (l == mid - first)
        buf[i] = mas[r++];
    else if (r == last - first)
        buf[i] = mas[l++];
    else if (strcmp(mas[l].sname, mas[r].sname) < 0)
        buf[i] = mas[l++];
    else
        buf[i] = mas[r++];
}
delete[] mas;
}
```

Comment: Просто интересно - большой массив - это сколько? Просто получить переполнение стека при глубине рекурсии `log n` - это надо постараться...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переполнение стека здесь возможно только при каких-то особых опциях компиляции. например, при компиляции в режиме `debug`. Ответ на ваш вопрос есть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557894/non-recursive-merge-sort), но вряд ли вам нужно именно это. Ещё не забудьте исправить ошибку поиска среднего элемента. Вместо

```
int mid = (first + last) / 2;
```

лучше написать

```
int mid = first + (last-first) / 2;
```

так как, я подозреваю, индексы неотрицательны - и первый вариант даст переполнение, если массив действительно, как Вы сказали, очень большой.

Comment: если это комплируется в 32 - битном режиме, а мы сортируем `int = 4 байта` то максимум размерность ~ 1млрд, если сложить будет меньше 2 млрд - предельное значение. А если 64 бита, то `int = 8 байт` и переполнить в ближайшее время не удастся.